# What are the implications of "Select Your Country or Region" when setting up an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, internationalization

I'm opening an iPhone after it has been reset to factory settings, and I'm asked to choose a language, and then to choose a country or region.

What are the implication of choosing a particular country? Will it lock me out of something? Can I change this setting later? Will it affect what apps I can download from the Apple app store?

Comment: afaik, it defines your default app store & currency, distance settings etc. Would only cause issues if you signed into Spain, yet all your credit & previous purchases were in the UK, for instance.

Comment: @Tetsujin default appstore; perhaps, but for sure this will directly be overridden by the current appstore location of your Apple ID.

Comment: Possibly this will set wifi channel and frequency ranges to the country's regulations also (for wifi only, because bluetooth regulations are the same worldwide, and cellular ranges are part of the initial cell negotiation process). In general this wouldn't get you less or more signal strenght however.

Comment: It's not something I ever have to mess with much, but my in-laws live in Spain, yet of course want everything to be set to their native UK settings. Sometimes it's a juggle, & we end up guessing each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change this setting later at any time.

It doesn't affect the AppStore. The region setting will affect the availability of certain features which aren't available in all regions yet such as Apple Pay and Apple News.

Apple News is only available if you set your region to Australia, UK or US. 
Apple Pay is additionally available in Canada.

Comment: ApplePay is UK too.

Comment: Yes, I meant that Apple Pay is available in Australia, the UK, US *and* Canada. Guess I didn't express that well.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yeah I just misread

Answer (score 3):

It will affect the time format (12 vs 24 hour), date format, currency display, temperature unit, and number formatting,. You can change later in Settings -> General -> Language and Region.